# Struts2 properties in JS

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

How to access S2 properties in JS. I tried the following code. Here I need to change span content dynamically in JS function.

In JS:

```
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = "<s:property value='%{#request.pagination.page_records*#request.pagination.total_pages-#request.pagination.page_records*(#request.pagination.page_number-1)}'/>";
```

In JSP:

```
<span id="index"><s:property value="%{#request.pagination.page_records*#request.pagination.total_pages-#request.pagination.page_records*(#request.pagination.page_number-1)}"/></span>
```

But nothing is going to displays. Any other solution to this.

Comment: What do you see in your page if your use: _<div>
<s:property value="%{#request.pagination.page_records*#request.pagination.total_pages-#request.pagination.page_records*(#request.pagination.page_number-1)}"/>
</div>_ If you see any thing then you s:property is correct if not there ir a problem there.

Comment: In alert it displays undefined.

Comment: alert(document.getElementById("index").value);

Comment: Please test the code I mentioned.

Comment: document.getElementById("index").innerHTML ="<s:property value='%{total}'/>";
alert(document.getElementById("index").innerHTML); i've changed some thing using action method. If I use this code it displays <s:property value='%{total}'/>.

Comment: Your js probably works just fine. But new value won't be set magically in js, just because it is js.